# How to get python's terminal error messages to be in color?

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I've been working with iPython notebooks for a while and I really appreciated how the error output (if I made a spelling/syntax error) was in color like this:
[image]

However, when I run code from the terminal (because iPython cannot do everything yet), I don't get any color, like so:
[image]

Of course that might vary by terminal/operating system, but I was curious if there are any easy package/plugin to make Python error output in the terminal to be in color please? or even what to look for (I run zsh on Ubuntu).

Comment: I suspect you might be able to import and use IPython's own exception printing handling for this.

Comment: yes it worked, thanks!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Digging through the IPython API reference turns up [`IPython.core.ultratb`](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.ultratb.html#module-IPython.core.ultratb), the module IPython itself uses for colorful exception formatting. You should be able to do

```
try:
    import IPython.core.ultratb
except ImportError:
    # No IPython. Use default exception printing.
    pass
else:
    import sys
    sys.excepthook = IPython.core.ultratb.ColorTB()
```

to check whether IPython is available, and if so, use its exception printer.